# Is there a generic way to detect lighters on opencv despite shadows or backgrounds' colors?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

EDIT: I don't think there is a generic way to detect object with openCV, the best way is to use deep learning algorithms

--

I'm new in openCV and I'm trying to find a generic way to detect lighters. I'm trying to code a solution that won't be perturbed by shadows, background's colors...

I have tried a lot of methods on openCV (bounding boxes, GrabCut, activeContour ...) but none works for all my data. I've tried removing the shadows, find the contours, the edges. When I change the function's param it works for some examples but it breaks the others...
I was inspired a lot by this tutorial
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

Is there a generic way to detect object on openCV?
Thank you very much for all you answers!!

I use python 3.7.3 and opencv version 3.4.4

Thanks again!

[perfect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Acz1.jpg),

[Issue: shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExUmx.jpg),

[Issue: white on white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VjLO.jpg).

Comment: Please show your code and a link to an image. We do not know what a lighter is in this context? Is that a cigarette lighter or something lighter on a darker background? You can post images to some free hosting service and then put the URL here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594459/how-can-you-measure-width-and-height-of-a-lighter-in-an-image-in-python on this forum.

Comment: I've just uploaded some images to explain my case. I'm referring to cigarette lighters. And for the code I really inspired myself from the tutorial I linked. Thank you for all your help :)